# How to access the patient-derived xenografts (PDXs) repository?

Tags: cancer, cell-line

I saw [this nature news item](http://www.nature.com/news/us-cancer-institute-to-overhaul-tumour-cell-lines-1.19364), it sounds that [Cellminer](https://discover.nci.nih.gov/cellminer/) is obsolete, is it right?

What are the new tools to analyze the "[new cell lines](https://www.jax.org/jax-mice-and-services/in-vivo-pharmacology/oncology-services/pdx-tumors#)"? Where's the PDX repository?

What about the European initiative that the article refers to?

I would be happy to see correlation between drugs and genes and similar capabilities as we can see on Cellminer.

Answer (score 2):

I already see for links when I try to search. Take a look at them below. Also if you can be precise about kind of data are you trying to find, it would be better

https://pdmr.cancer.gov/

http://cdt.northwestern.edu/news/patient-derived-xenograft-repository-now-available-researchers

http://www.epo-berlin.com/epo-tumor-models-xenografts.html

http://www.proxe.org/

http://data-analysis.charite.de/care/

http://www.oasis-genomics.org/

http://www.cbioportal.org/

Hope one of these above will serve the purpose for you.

Update: added some more links that might serve. As for the Cellminer the last update was 2012.

Comment: not sure if you will get something exactly like cellminer but take a look at those link and download the files and see to what extent you can use them. Cellminer is still not retired but probably it is not being updated. I could not find any log in their database so probably thinking they are not updating it now.

Comment: also take a look at this http://data-analysis.charite.de/care/ . to be honest cellminer update was not done since 2012, that is what I understand. Also take a look at OASIS and cbioportal as well